# RSPEC get Abstract Syntax Tree of all Tests / Expectations

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

Given a certain part of RSPEC (psuedo):

```
describe Person do
  describe '#name' do
    it 'is present' do
      expect(name).not_to be_blank
    end
  end
end
```

How could I get an abstract syntax tree of that, such that it looks somewhat like (heavy psuedo):

```
[
  describe: {
    name: Person,
    content: [
      describe: {
        name: '#name',
        content: [
          it: { tests: [{what: name, condition: 'not blank'}]
        ]
      }
  }
]
```

Is there a built in facility to show the entire tree of execution in RSPEC?

Answer (score 0):

RSpec doesn't generate a syntax tree when it runs. It provides methods (in the appearance of a DSL) which generates classes and methods under the hood. You will likely need to look in to the Ruby AST to determine how that works.

Also, there has been great RSpec syntax conversion gem created called [`transpec`](https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec). It does some work with AST that I suggest checking out.